# Concurrent LRU cache implementation

Tags: java, multithreading

I need thread safe and efficient `LRU` cache implementation code.
below code is not thread safe. Is this code can be enhanced using `ConcurrentHashMap`.
Thanks in advance.

```
private class LruCache<A, B> extends LinkedHashMap<A, B> {
    private final int maxEntries;

    public LruCache(final int maxEntries) {
        super(maxEntries + 1, 1.0f, true);
        this.maxEntries = maxEntries;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(final Map.Entry<A, B> eldest) {
        return super.size() > maxEntries;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using guava cache: http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/package-frame.html

Comment: [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap/wiki/Design) beget [Guava's Cache](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap/blob/wiki/ConcurrentCachingAtGoogle.pdf) which beget [Caffeine](http://highscalability.com/blog/2016/1/25/design-of-a-modern-cache.html).

Comment: The link to https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine should really be much higher.  This is a really nice, well documented, well written package.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best you can do is to make it thread-safe is to wrap it with [`Collections.synchronizedMap(map)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-) as explained in the javadoc:

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads
>   access a linked hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads
>   modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally.
>   This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that
>   naturally encapsulates the map. If no such object exists, the map
>   should be "wrapped" using the `Collections.synchronizedMap` method. This
>   is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized
>   access to the map:

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap(...));
```

However it is not enough to make it fully thread-safe you sill need to protect any iteration over the content of the map using the instance of the wrapped map as object's monitor:

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(map);
...
Set s = m.keySet();  // Needn't be in synchronized block
...
synchronized (m) {  // Synchronizing on m, not s!
    Iterator i = s.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
    while (i.hasNext())
      foo(i.next());
}
```

---

This is pretty much all you can **easily** do with what we have out of the box in the `JDK`, if you want something thread-safe and more efficient, you should rather look at [`Cache`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) from **Google Guava**.

*Here is an example of a `LRU` cache with a max size of `2` built with `guava`:*

```
ConcurrentMap<String, String> cache = 
    CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(2L)
        .<String, String>build().asMap();
cache.put("a", "b");
cache.put("b", "c");
System.out.println(cache);
cache.put("a", "d");
System.out.println(cache);
cache.put("c", "d");
System.out.println(cache);
```

**Output:**

```
{b=c, a=b}
{b=c, a=d}
{c=d, a=d}
```

Comment: Why map needs to be synchronized for iteration, i didn't get it .. can u please shed some light ?

Comment: @SahilGupta because otherwise you could still face ConcurrentModificationException if for example some entries are removed while iterating over your map entries

Comment: Iterating over the entries of a map is not an atomic operation, it does internally multiple read accesses to the content of the map, even if those accesses are all individually atomic, it is not enough to prevent  ConcurrentModificationException, that's why you need to do it within a synchronized block as stated into the javadoc

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Sorry, my bad. The mutex is the map instance itself (unless you request otherwise). I will delete my previous comment with incorrect information to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 5):

Found Guava's [Cache](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html). Haven't used it myself.

> A Cache is similar to ConcurrentMap, but not quite the same.

Source: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained

Example:

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .maximumSize(1000)
       .build(
           new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
             public Graph load(Key key) { // no checked exception
               return createExpensiveGraph(key);
             }
           });

...
return graphs.getUnchecked(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Compared to using `Collections.synchronozedMap()` as wrapper, I think it's better to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` and a `ConcurrentLinkedList` together and implement `java.util.Map` interface and potentially `List` interface if you needed to. However you need some custom logic between the operation on the internal map and list to ensure concurrency holds. But still the performance can be better than a fully `synchronized` map.

Comment: could you please share the implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android's solution, which is thread safe (it says "This class is thread-safe" ) :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache

Sadly, however, it doesn't seem to offer concurrency. Just synchronizing stuff...

Current code:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package android.util;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * BEGIN LAYOUTLIB CHANGE
 * This is a custom version that doesn't use the non standard LinkedHashMap#eldest.
 * END LAYOUTLIB CHANGE
 *
 * A cache that holds strong references to a limited number of values. Each time
 * a value is accessed, it is moved to the head of a queue. When a value is
 * added to a full cache, the value at the end of that queue is evicted and may
 * become eligible for garbage collection.
 *
 * <p>If your cached values hold resources that need to be explicitly released,
 * override {@link #entryRemoved}.
 *
 * <p>If a cache miss should be computed on demand for the corresponding keys,
 * override {@link #create}. This simplifies the calling code, allowing it to
 * assume a value will always be returned, even when there's a cache miss.
 *
 * <p>By default, the cache size is measured in the number of entries. Override
 * {@link #sizeOf} to size the cache in different units. For example, this cache
 * is limited to 4MiB of bitmaps:
 * <pre>   {@code
 *   int cacheSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024; // 4MiB
 *   LruCache<String, Bitmap> bitmapCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
 *       protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
 *           return value.getByteCount();
 *       }
 *   }}</pre>
 *
 * <p>This class is thread-safe. Perform multiple cache operations atomically by
 * synchronizing on the cache: <pre>   {@code
 *   synchronized (cache) {
 *     if (cache.get(key) == null) {
 *         cache.put(key, value);
 *     }
 *   }}</pre>
 *
 * <p>This class does not allow null to be used as a key or value. A return
 * value of null from {@link #get}, {@link #put} or {@link #remove} is
 * unambiguous: the key was not in the cache.
 *
 * <p>This class appeared in Android 3.1 (Honeycomb MR1); it's available as part
 * of <a href="http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html">Android's
 * Support Package</a> for earlier releases.
 */
public class LruCache<K, V> {
    private final LinkedHashMap<K, V> map;

    /** Size of this cache in units. Not necessarily the number of elements. */
    private int size;
    private int maxSize;

    private int putCount;
    private int createCount;
    private int evictionCount;
    private int hitCount;
    private int missCount;

    /**
     * @param maxSize for caches that do not override {@link #sizeOf}, this is
     *     the maximum number of entries in the cache. For all other caches,
     *     this is the maximum sum of the sizes of the entries in this cache.
     */
    public LruCache(int maxSize) {
        if (maxSize <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxSize <= 0");
        }
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        this.map = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>(0, 0.75f, true);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the size of the cache.
     * @param maxSize The new maximum size.
     *
     * @hide
     */
    public void resize(int maxSize) {
        if (maxSize <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxSize <= 0");
        }

        synchronized (this) {
            this.maxSize = maxSize;
        }
        trimToSize(maxSize);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the value for {@code key} if it exists in the cache or can be
     * created by {@code #create}. If a value was returned, it is moved to the
     * head of the queue. This returns null if a value is not cached and cannot
     * be created.
     */
    public final V get(K key) {
        if (key == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("key == null");
        }

        V mapValue;
        synchronized (this) {
            mapValue = map.get(key);
            if (mapValue != null) {
                hitCount++;
                return mapValue;
            }
            missCount++;
        }

        /*
         * Attempt to create a value. This may take a long time, and the map
         * may be different when create() returns. If a conflicting value was
         * added to the map while create() was working, we leave that value in
         * the map and release the created value.
         */

        V createdValue = create(key);
        if (createdValue == null) {
            return null;
        }

        synchronized (this) {
            createCount++;
            mapValue = map.put(key, createdValue);

            if (mapValue != null) {
                // There was a conflict so undo that last put
                map.put(key, mapValue);
            } else {
                size += safeSizeOf(key, createdValue);
            }
        }

        if (mapValue != null) {
            entryRemoved(false, key, createdValue, mapValue);
            return mapValue;
        } else {
            trimToSize(maxSize);
            return createdValue;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Caches {@code value} for {@code key}. The value is moved to the head of
     * the queue.
     *
     * @return the previous value mapped by {@code key}.
     */
    public final V put(K key, V value) {
        if (key == null || value == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("key == null || value == null");
        }

        V previous;
        synchronized (this) {
            putCount++;
            size += safeSizeOf(key, value);
            previous = map.put(key, value);
            if (previous != null) {
                size -= safeSizeOf(key, previous);
            }
        }

        if (previous != null) {
            entryRemoved(false, key, previous, value);
        }

        trimToSize(maxSize);
        return previous;
    }

    /**
     * @param maxSize the maximum size of the cache before returning. May be -1
     *     to evict even 0-sized elements.
     */
    private void trimToSize(int maxSize) {
        while (true) {
            K key;
            V value;
            synchronized (this) {
                if (size < 0 || (map.isEmpty() && size != 0)) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(getClass().getName()
                            + ".sizeOf() is reporting inconsistent results!");
                }

                if (size <= maxSize) {
                    break;
                }

                // BEGIN LAYOUTLIB CHANGE
                // get the last item in the linked list.
                // This is not efficient, the goal here is to minimize the changes
                // compared to the platform version.
                Map.Entry<K, V> toEvict = null;
                for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    toEvict = entry;
                }
                // END LAYOUTLIB CHANGE

                if (toEvict == null) {
                    break;
                }

                key = toEvict.getKey();
                value = toEvict.getValue();
                map.remove(key);
                size -= safeSizeOf(key, value);
                evictionCount++;
            }

            entryRemoved(true, key, value, null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes the entry for {@code key} if it exists.
     *
     * @return the previous value mapped by {@code key}.
     */
    public final V remove(K key) {
        if (key == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("key == null");
        }

        V previous;
        synchronized (this) {
            previous = map.remove(key);
            if (previous != null) {
                size -= safeSizeOf(key, previous);
            }
        }

        if (previous != null) {
            entryRemoved(false, key, previous, null);
        }

        return previous;
    }

    /**
     * Called for entries that have been evicted or removed. This method is
     * invoked when a value is evicted to make space, removed by a call to
     * {@link #remove}, or replaced by a call to {@link #put}. The default
     * implementation does nothing.
     *
     * <p>The method is called without synchronization: other threads may
     * access the cache while this method is executing.
     *
     * @param evicted true if the entry is being removed to make space, false
     *     if the removal was caused by a {@link #put} or {@link #remove}.
     * @param newValue the new value for {@code key}, if it exists. If non-null,
     *     this removal was caused by a {@link #put}. Otherwise it was caused by
     *     an eviction or a {@link #remove}.
     */
    protected void entryRemoved(boolean evicted, K key, V oldValue, V newValue) {}

    /**
     * Called after a cache miss to compute a value for the corresponding key.
     * Returns the computed value or null if no value can be computed. The
     * default implementation returns null.
     *
     * <p>The method is called without synchronization: other threads may
     * access the cache while this method is executing.
     *
     * <p>If a value for {@code key} exists in the cache when this method
     * returns, the created value will be released with {@link #entryRemoved}
     * and discarded. This can occur when multiple threads request the same key
     * at the same time (causing multiple values to be created), or when one
     * thread calls {@link #put} while another is creating a value for the same
     * key.
     */
    protected V create(K key) {
        return null;
    }

    private int safeSizeOf(K key, V value) {
        int result = sizeOf(key, value);
        if (result < 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Negative size: " + key + "=" + value);
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the size of the entry for {@code key} and {@code value} in
     * user-defined units.  The default implementation returns 1 so that size
     * is the number of entries and max size is the maximum number of entries.
     *
     * <p>An entry's size must not change while it is in the cache.
     */
    protected int sizeOf(K key, V value) {
        return 1;
    }

    /**
     * Clear the cache, calling {@link #entryRemoved} on each removed entry.
     */
    public final void evictAll() {
        trimToSize(-1); // -1 will evict 0-sized elements
    }

    /**
     * For caches that do not override {@link #sizeOf}, this returns the number
     * of entries in the cache. For all other caches, this returns the sum of
     * the sizes of the entries in this cache.
     */
    public synchronized final int size() {
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * For caches that do not override {@link #sizeOf}, this returns the maximum
     * number of entries in the cache. For all other caches, this returns the
     * maximum sum of the sizes of the entries in this cache.
     */
    public synchronized final int maxSize() {
        return maxSize;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of times {@link #get} returned a value that was
     * already present in the cache.
     */
    public synchronized final int hitCount() {
        return hitCount;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of times {@link #get} returned null or required a new
     * value to be created.
     */
    public synchronized final int missCount() {
        return missCount;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of times {@link #create(Object)} returned a value.
     */
    public synchronized final int createCount() {
        return createCount;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of times {@link #put} was called.
     */
    public synchronized final int putCount() {
        return putCount;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of values that have been evicted.
     */
    public synchronized final int evictionCount() {
        return evictionCount;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a copy of the current contents of the cache, ordered from least
     * recently accessed to most recently accessed.
     */
    public synchronized final Map<K, V> snapshot() {
        return new LinkedHashMap<K, V>(map);
    }

    @Override public synchronized final String toString() {
        int accesses = hitCount + missCount;
        int hitPercent = accesses != 0 ? (100 * hitCount / accesses) : 0;
        return String.format("LruCache[maxSize=%d,hits=%d,misses=%d,hitRate=%d%%]",
                maxSize, hitCount, missCount, hitPercent);
    }
}
```

Comment: outside a context of an android application someone using this code should replace `int hitCount` by `long hitCount`.

Comment: @Duloren Technically true, but this seems to be used just for statistics, so maybe a better thing would be to avoid having it public too, and show it only in toString, or just remove it entirely because it's not so useful anyway. Or count it only on debug version... You get the point...

Answer (score 0):

1. While using LinkedHashMap as LRU Cache, we have to use Collections.synchronizedMap to handle concurrency. This would mean that parallel hits to fetch value from the cache will slow down. [sample implementation](https://prasunejohn.blogspot.com/2020/11/write-concurrent-lru-cache-using.html)
2. Alternate approach - While the LRU cache data can be expected to have very less frequent writes, one should expect a lot of frequent reads. So using ReadWriteLock with ConcurrentHashMap and ConcurrentLinkedQueue internally and managing get data using a ReadLock will help increase the performance with respect to lot of parallel reads. [sample implementation](https://prasunejohn.blogspot.com/2020/11/write-concurrent-lru-cache-using_28.html)
   But this approach has a major disadvantage with respect to time taken for searching an entry if the scale of data to be retained is huge. This is because the ConcurrentLinkedQueue needs to be scanned to re-add after picking up the data every time.

So, I think synchronized LinkedHashMap will be the ideal solution if the scale of data to be maintained in LRU Cache is huge and approach#2 will help only if the scale of data on to be retained is less.
Also, for better performance while retaining large scale data in synchronized LinkedHashMap, it could be a good idea to partition the data into multiple LinkedHashMaps with a hashing algorithm to decide which LinkedHashMap will have the data so that parallel reads can happen on different partitioned LinkedHashMaps.